# No automatic _id generated

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have this code for adding a new item to the database, like so:

```js
let parking = new Parking({
  name: req.body.name,
  country: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.country),
  reservationsEmail: req.body.reservationsEmail,
  location: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.location),
  commissionPercentage: req.body.commission,
  isConcept: true,
});

parking.save()
.then(parking => {
  res.send(parking);
}).catch(err => {
  res.send(err);
});
```

This gives me an error that `_id` is required before saving:

```js
{ MongooseError: document must have an _id before saving
    at new MongooseError (/Users/robin/www_node/parkos/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:14:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/robin/www_node/parkos/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:259:18)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
  message: 'document must have an _id before saving',
  name: 'MongooseError' }
```

Why isn't the `_id` automatically added like it supposed to?

This is the model I use:

```js
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId  = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;
const isEmail   = require('validator/lib/isEmail');
const slugify   = require('../../lib/utils.js').slugify;

let parkingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default() {
      return slugify(this.name);
    }
  },
  country: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Country',
    required: true,
  },
  reservationsEmail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: [
      isEmail,
      'Please enter a valid emailaddress'
    ],
  },
  discountPercentage: {
    type: String,
    required() {
      return !this.isConcept;
    },
    default: 0,
  },
  location: {
    type: ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Location'
  },
  commissionPercentage: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  isConcept: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: false,
  },
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

const Parking = mongoose.model('Parking', parkingSchema);
module.exports = Parking;
```

Values for both country and location in request:

```js
console.log('Location', parking.location, typeof parking.location); // Location 5caa0993ab95691762dc1a33 object
console.log('Country', parking.country, typeof parking.country); // Country 5caa04e6b6969a708080f8dd object
```

So when I post it via Postman:

```
{
    "name": "Test Parking",
    "reservationsEmail": "example@gmail.com",
    "country": "5caa04e6b6969a708080f8dd",
    "location": "5caa0993ab95691762dc1a33",
    "commission": "20"
}
```

It works like expected... via the Fetch API though...

```js
let formData = new URLSearchParams([...new FormData(form).entries()]);

fetch('/parkings/create-concept', {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
  credentials: "include",
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model.js have you this line ?

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Parking', parkingSchema);
```

=======================

Country and location must be instance of objectId, try to set them with

```
    mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.myfield);
```

Comment: Yeah I do, forgot to put that in. Edited the question

Comment: Can you print the value of req.body.location and req.body.country

Comment: which version of mongoose are you running ? npm list mongoose, i don't reproduce the error

Comment: Have you imported Parking model inside route file, also Country and Location?

Comment: The latest version: `mongoose@5.5.2`